# why serv.bind in this tutorial expected to always returns exception?

Tags: python

I got the code below from multiple sources after googling "port scanner using python"

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()

for port in range(65535):  
 
    try:  
        serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) # create a new socket
        serv.bind((host,port)) # bind socket with address
            
    except: 
        print('[OPEN] Port open :',port) #print open port number
 
    serv.close()
```

The code above will display the open port when the code under `except` is executed. But why do the line `serv.bind` returns an exception with the open port number? I thought since the port is open, `serv.bind` will connect successfully instead?

Comment: `bind` doesn't _connect_ to a port, it `bind`s a port.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the exception generated? It's a reliable way to answer the question "why does it return an exception?".  Low-number ports are probably giving you `Permission denied`.

Comment: @Mark is returns mostly "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions", and only one " Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

Comment: Does that answer your question then? Some ports are off limits to unprivileged users, and other ports may be in use by another process.

Comment: @Mark not yet, as why `serv.bind` there will always return the errors above (even port 12345 for example), but when I try to connect using `socket.connect` on lets say port number 12345, the connection will be successful then?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answerable question. If you are trying to solve a particular issue, you need to debug the particular exception.  I have no trouble using the code above to bind to port 12345. If it's telling you the port is in use, then you should figure out why. If it's giving a different error, then start there. Here, you are trying to bind to thousands of ports and getting a variety of errors. If helps if you can create a reproducible example one _one_ problem.

Comment: Could you link to the tutorial source? This code is scanning the ports on your local machine and printing the ones that are not available or already in use.  Most port scanner tutorials I've found instead target another address and use socket.connect() to look for open ports.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety here's one of the tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-simple-port-scanner-with-sockets/

Comment: @imin - I think that might simply be a bad tutorial.  If you check pretty much any other link other than the geeksforgeeks one, you'll see that they use `socket.connect()`, and also have warnings to do only use it to a host you have explicit permission to scan the ports on, as port scanning on a device you don't have permission for can be construed as a crime.